# how to read buffer backwards? x86 TASM

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm, dosbox

I need to display the buffer backwards than it is at first

```
....
MOV cx, ax
    MOV si, offset skBuf
    MOV di, offset raBuf
 work
    MOV dl, [si]
    
    MOV [di], dl
    INC si
    INC di
    LOOP    work
....
```

Comment: Start with a pointer to the end of the destination and `dec di`.

Comment: More precisely, do `ADD si, ax; DEC si` before the loop, so that `si` points to the last element, then in the loop change `INC si` into `DEC si` in order to move backwards as you read the bytes to copy.

Comment: You are the best! I love you!!!!

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Instead of an extra `dec si` before the loop, put the `dec si` at the top of the loop, before the load.  So you can still enter the loop with SI pointing to one-past-the-end of the input buffer.